# CSS @font-face custom font doesn't work if font source is http://xxx

Tags: php, html, css

So, my problem is that these custom fonts don't work when I add them to a separate .css file and include them like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://lib.mywebsite.eu/content/content.css">
```

The font just doesn't display. The CSS file was pointing fonts this way:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'JosefinSansThin';
src: url('fonts/JosefinSansThin.eot');
src: url('fonts/JosefinSansThin.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/JosefinSansThin.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('fonts/JosefinSansThin.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/JosefinSansThin.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/JosefinSansThin.svg#JosefinSansThin') format('svg');}
```

So I tried to copy the whole css into the html file like this:

```
<style type='text/css'>
    @font-face {
font-family: 'JosefinSansThin';
src: url('/subdom/lib/content/fonts/JosefinSansThin.eot');
src: url('/subdom/lib/content/fonts/JosefinSansThin.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/subdom/lib/content/fonts/JosefinSansThin.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/subdom/lib/content/fonts/JosefinSansThin.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/subdom/lib/content/fonts/JosefinSansThin.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/subdom/lib/content/fonts/JosefinSansThin.svg#JosefinSansThin') format('svg');}</style>
```

And boom! It worked.
But I don't want to use it only in index.php and I need it to be in other html/php files --> it needs to be in external file. So my next attempt was to include it with php:

```
<style type='text/css'>
    <?php
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/subdom/lib/content/content.css';
    ?>
</style>
```

It worked, but because of the way include works, in the external css there has to be the same path to the font as if it was in the index.php - '/subdom/lib/content/fonts...' and therefore I can't use it in other folder than the root.
It would all be fine if I could point to it with address http://lib.mywebsite.eu/content/fonts/JosefineSansThin.xxx (which is equal to http://mywebsite.eu/subdom/lib/content/fonts/JosefineSansThin.xxx)
Any idea why it doesn't work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the links absolute in the CSS file itself:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'JosefinSansThin';
src: url('/subdom/lib/content/fonts/JosefinSansThin.eot');
src: url('/subdom/lib/content/fonts/JosefinSansThin.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/subdom/lib/content/fonts/JosefinSansThin.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/subdom/lib/content/fonts/JosefinSansThin.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/subdom/lib/content/fonts/JosefinSansThin.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/subdom/lib/content/fonts/JosefinSansThin.svg#JosefinSansThin') format('svg');
```

Making the links absolute will allow them to work *regardless* of the folder you're in.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's how I have it right now, and I use PHP's include to include it into the index.php. But If I used it in php that is not in main folder (for ex. on http://mywebsite.eu/blog/index.php) it wouldn't work because address http://mywebsite.eu/blog/subdom/lib... doesn't exist.

Comment: That shouldn't happen -- the initial slash indicates the root. If you reference it in http://mywebsite.eu/blog/index.php, it should refer to http://mywebsite.eu/subdom/lib.

Comment: Omg I am so dumb! Ofc. I didn't have the links absolute... Thanks for your help, I feel so embarrassed

Comment: Haha no worries -- glad you fixed the problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the URL suppose to be:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://lib.mywebsite.eu/subdom/lib/content/content.css">`
?

Relative URLs in a CSS file is relative to the file's location.

`url('fonts/JosefinSansThin.eot')` located in a CSS file at `http://lib.mywebsite.eu/content/content.css` would be equivalent to `http://lib.mywebsite.eu/content/fonts/JosefinSansThin.eot`

**Update:** If worst comes to worst, just use absolute paths.

Comment: No, I have a directory /subdom in root directory and .htaccess that redirects http://anything.mywebsite.eu to http://mywebsite.eu/subdom/anything the .htaccess can be found here: http://pastebin.com/GhYAPSiz